# Customized home page for each user in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have an urgent requirement in which there should be Customized Home page for each user.

For example when a admin user visits the site then on home page he should see the links of those webpages or doc which is relevant to him, same for management  or user.

There should be the option to add that link to his favorite so that next time when he visit the page it should be in favorite section of home page for that particular user only.

Comment: hi, you can use web parts to do this, 1. include all the web parts in the page and set targeted audience for each web part

Answer (score 1):

Like Jussi's suggestion. Wanted to elaborate on the Audience piece. You can target:

- list or library items to an audience
- a navigation link to an audience
- a Web Part to an audience

See these articles for details: https://support.office.com/en-au/article/Target-content-to-specific-audiences-33d84cb6-14ed-4e53-a426-74c38ea32293
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc261958%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Redirect all users to their MySite by default, and configure user MySites as desired.